# Dependency Property Binding and updating to a custom control -- It updates, but apparently not both ways?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, dependency-properties

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string MyText { ... }
}
```

XAML:

```
<my:MySpecialTextBox Text="{Binding MyText}" />
```

Custom Control:

```
public class MySpecialTextBox : TextBox
{
    static MySpecialTextBox()
    {
        TextProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MySpecialTextBox),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
            {
                BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
                DefaultValue = string.empty,
                PropertyChangedCallback = OnTextPropertyChanged
            });
    }

    private static void OnTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = d as MySpecialTextBox;

        if (control != null)
        {
            control.Text = SomeAdjustedValue((string)e.NewValue);
        }
    }
}
```

---

The problem is that while the DependencyProperty in the custom control does adjust properly, it does not update the ViewModel. I realize that this *seems* as if it should be a CoerceValueCallback due to the naming of SomeAdjustedValue, but Coercion does not change the ViewModel value either. I can't seem to update the value in my ViewModel if it was the trigger for the OnTextPropertyChanged callback to begin with... I did a debug trace and it does not go through the ViewModel a second time with the new value. Not sure what to do here to fix this.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand- you are expecting a change in the ViewModel, raised to the UI via PropertyChanged notification, to update the UI and then, because of the binding callback, to subsequently be routed back to the ViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

In the FrameworkPropertyMetadata, there are different constructors you can use. Use one with the FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions parameter.  The FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault option will turn on two way binding by default, otherwise it's just one way.

Edit: So you did, I should stop trying to answer questions when I'm sick.

Comment: Umm, I did set BindsTwoWayByDefault to true.

Answer (score 0):

A disclaimer first- this smells like logic that should live inside of the ViewModel, not in the UI binding.

That said, if you are set on doing it this way, I think that you need to first check whether the "Adjusted Value" is different than the one already provided (to avoid looping indefinitely), then use [DependencyProperty.SetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597473.aspx) to set the value of the dependency property on the control, rather than just setting it's Text property.

Comment: This did not work either... it sets the value on my custom control once again, but it does not update the view-model.

Comment: SetValue() replaces the binding;  use SetCurrentValue() instead.

Answer (score 0):

`TextBox.Text` is a binding, and you are replacing that binding with a string value in `OnTextPropertyChanged`, so the property is no longer bound to your datasource.

I think you would need to get the binding on `TextBox.Text` and update the source, however I wouldn't recommend doing that since you'd be mixing your Business Logic layer with your UI layer.

If you only want a display some custom formatting, I would do it in a Converter so it doesn't actually change your data source's value. If you want to change the actual data source value, I would do that with the ViewModel's `PropertyChanged` event

Comment: See my answer below - using .NET 4 one can now call SetCurrentValue(dp, value) and set the value without affecting the binding.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
private static void OnTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = d as MySpecialTextBox;

    if (control != null)
    {
        control.SetCurrentValue(TextBox.TextProperty, SomeAdjustedValue((string)e.NewValue));
    }
}
```

The SetCurrentValue() method ensures that the binding is preserved, where a simple SetValue() which is what is called under the hood if you use the Text property setter will remove any binding.

Comment: Note that you may also need to set some member boolean flag e.g.  "ignoreTextPropertyChangedEvent" while you call SetCurrentValue(); otherwise you might get stuck in an infinite loop.